# Connecting to an Azure database the first time

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, azure, authentication, runtime-error

I have deployed a C# MVC4 internet application to Azure and have retrieved the connection string from the database portion of the dashboard and have inserted this into my solution.

When browsing to the controller, I am getting an error as follows:

> Login failed for user

The database I am using is a new database with no tables or data in the database.

Do I need to install any add-ons or set up any settings to be able to connect and use the database? Is the entity framework used on the Azure side of the server? Usually an MVC application will create the database structure the first time the database in connected to. Is this the same with connecting to an Azure database?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Do the login credentials for the database work for you outside of the application? e.g. try connecting with SSMS or by following the manage link in the Azure Management Web Portal

Comment: Yes, it should work fine. Have you verified that you can connect via Management Studio. Also, you need to create a DB login in the MASTER DB, and then create a db user in your specific database that is linked to the DB login in MASTER

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a simple problem with the connection string.